# $Φ(T(v),T(w)) = Φ(v,w) \to T$ is an isometry

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\Phi : V \times V \rightarrow K$ be a nondegenerate bilinear form, $V$ a finite-dimensional $K$-vector space, $T: V \rightarrow V$ a mapping with 
$$\Phi(T(v),T(w)) = \Phi(v,w)$$

for all $v,w \in V.$

I have to show that in this case $T$ is already an isometry. Can anyone tell me what exactly I need to show now?

Comment: This is usually taken to be the *definition* of an isometry, though usually one only sees that applied to $\Phi$ that are also symmetric (or Hermitian).

Comment: how you define an isometry in a different way than $\phi(Tv,Tw) = \phi(v,w)$ to begin with?

Comment: In the lecture we had the assumption that T is an endomorphism which is missing here. Apart from this we proved that T is an isometry is equivalent to

M(T,B)^t M(Φ,B) M(T,B) = M(Φ,B) for all basis and that T* T = Id